# Set Named Color through Interface Builder resulting in `NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException`

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-storyboard

I have a BaseViewController that has
`@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable UIColor *color;`

my project also has a Color.assets (a named color) so I able to give color to the inspectable color above through my storyboard.
Then when I run my project, it crash with this message.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named IBColor because no class named IBColor was found; the class needs to be defined in source code or linked in from a library (ensure the class is part of the correct target)'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 857.14 - Device: iPhone X  (51A3C6D4-C935-4468-B811-2289019EE782) - Runtime: iOS 12.4 (16G73) - DeviceType: iPhone X
```

I am confused what to do.

I expect it can run normally and the color can be set in that storyboards. but it just crash

Comment: The most significant part of the error message is ***no class named IBColor was found***

Comment: will it be generated later at the runtime by the Xcode, another storyboard can use the named color just fine without crashing. @vadian.